# UITableView loads slowly and repeatedly loads cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

Hi: I have a `UITableView` that is loaded from an XIB file using the following line:

```
rulebookEditView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Rulebooks" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

The view is then added as a subview, and a function of the view's class is called that registers cells and loads the table view:

```
[self.settingsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RulebookEditorCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RulebookEditorCell"];
[self.settingsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RulebookEditorXLCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RulebookEditorXLCell"];

//Get the data etc.

[self.settingsTableView reloadData];
```

Now here's the strange part. I put a log in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function to log the `indexPath.row` value. This ended up logging the following (I condensed it):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
```

I have no idea why it would load 21 cells then immediately load the first 7 twice.

It should be noted that there are 7 cells visible at once on the screen. There are 21 cells, all in 1 section.

I put a breakpoint on `reloadData`, and it is indeed only called once by my code.

I'm guessing that `registerNib:` forces the table view to refresh, as does loading it from the XIB file...? If so, is there a way to prevent this or improve performance? Because this is causing about 500ms of lag on the main thread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say this, but this turned out being a classic case of being trigger-happy with calling intensive functions. My `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` function looked like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return ([[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] class] == [RulebookEditorXLCell class] ? 160 : 75);
}
```

I changed it to this, and it works much better now:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return ([self cellClassTypeForIndexPath:indexPath] == [RulebookEditorXLCell class] ? 160 : 75);
}

//Returns the class of the object that should be shown for a particular setting
-(Class)cellClassTypeForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 4 || indexPath.row == 9 || indexPath.row == 10 || indexPath.row == 11 || indexPath.row == 13 || indexPath.row == 14 || indexPath.row == 19 || indexPath.row == 20)  {

        //Return the large customized cell
        return [RulebookEditorXLCell class];

    } else {

        //Return the normal customized cell
        return [RulebookEditorCell class];
    }
}
```

And, of course, the log now outputs:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Silly mistake that caused a lot of wasted time, but I hope this helps someone else.

**Moral of the story: Don't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.**

Comment: That's a classic mistake -- heightForRow should never call cellForRow, but it seems like this is frequently done.